# Where to find extensive Raspbian documentation, e.g. for /etc/dphys-swapfile?

Tags: raspbian

Yesterday I solved a swap issue (composer project) by extending the /etc/dphys-swapfile. I found information for doing this on http://raspberrypimaker.com/adding-swap-to-the-raspberrypi/.

I restarted the Pi and could see the difference with the command `free -h`. But after my issue I don't need that extended swap anymore. So I wanted to write a script that extends the swap, executes a command and shrinks the swap again without having to reboot.

Does anybody know where to find documentation for Raspbian regarding this and other custom tweaks? The official sources below are quite limited:

- https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/
- https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianDocumentation

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/dphys-swapfile.8.html | https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/193815/271585

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raspbian is based on Debian and you can mostly use Debian documentation for it. Look [here](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianDocumentation).
If that is not enough, the [Debian Administrators Handbook](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/) is considered one of the best resources out there.
Its free online , but you can still buy it on paper, too.

The easiest way is probably the inbuilt help, called "manpages" in the UNIX world.
Use

```
apropos keyword
```

to search for the *keyword*. Use

```
man name-of-manpage
```

to open the manual page with the given name. Almost all Linux commands have a manpage with the same name. Unsurprisingly

```
man dhphys-swapfile
```

works out of the box. For fun, try

```
man man
```

Comment: Thanks!I knew about the man command but wasn't aware that it would also provide info regarding that file. So thanks for pointing that out. I should've also figured out that I could use the debian documentation. Weirdly enough I expected Rapbian to do the same...